# Need help making the nodules on buddhas head

Tags: texturing, sculpting

hey guys im working on a buddha statue for our server in conan exiles and i need help understanding how to make the details on buddhas head. I want to sculpt one of the spherical nodules you see on his head and then essentially be able to copy and paste them so im not sitting here doing one by one when he has 100+ of them on his head. Just as a forewarning i am using dynamic topology for sculpting with mirroring on incase that changes anything.

[image: my sculpt]

[image: what i need to replicate]

Comment: You don't need to sculpt them IMO. Model just one and array it along the curves.

Comment: im 100% new to blender so im not quite entirely sure what you mean by this? should i open a new file and try to make a sphere and what do you mean by array it along the curves?

Comment: nvm i figured it out =D making spheres and torus's to make the single model then ive been using shift + d to duplicate it and place them and then mirroring it on the other side. thanks guys

Answer (score 5):

Model the detail and array it along the *curve*. Place many curves with the arrayed meshes around the head.
[image]

Add a curve and wrap it around the head. Select your mesh (detail), add an ***array modifier*** to it and increase its count. Adjust its offset also. Make sure that the curve and mesh have the origins point set in the same position. Next add a ***curve modifier*** to your mesh. Now when you translate the curve's segments the mesh follows it.
[image]

Comment: You can add a shrinkwrap modifier to the curve so that if follows the curvature of the head.

Answer (score -1):

answered above

I figured it out, making spheres and torus's to make the single model then I've been using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate it and place them and then mirroring it on the other side.

So from sculpting mode I went back into object mode, once in object mode I made a sphere under the create tab.

I scaled the object down using the tools, next I created a torus under the create menu.

I scaled the torus down and placed it into the sphere, then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the torus and moved it outwards along the z axis.

Then used the scale tool to shrink the second one down, and continued this til I got 4 rings.

Upon the last ring i selected the sphere to drag it out more and sized it down so the center would protrude more.

Once the bead or nodule was to my liking i selected the base ring along with the other rings and then selected the sphere last (to make sure it'd be the parent), press <kbd>Ctrp</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and selected object, to parent them all together.

After parenting them I could <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and duplicate the entire bead/nodule.